# Symfony2 - doctrine:generate:entity throws 'Bundle "AcmeBlogBundle" does not exist' error

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I am trying to generate CRUD using command line in `Symfony3` I am getting error as below

[image]

I tried clearing cache using below command line

`php bin/console cache:clear`

Still I am getting this error.

Comment: Does the bundle exist? Is it added to `AppKernel`?

Comment: I haven't added, I am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEsC5mMx32Q tutorial. It is not saying anything about it

Comment: It just doesn't cover creation of the bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate/create the bundle `AcmeBlogBundle` first and add the bundle to the kernel in `app/AppKernel.php`.

Otherwise Doctrine doesn't know about the **alias** `AcmeBlogBundle:` that is used to resolve the class to an entity. Doctrine can't resolve the alias to an existing namespace and doesn't know where to put the `Entity` class.

Run the following command to create i.e. the `AcmeBlogBundle` bundle.

```
app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme\Bundle\AcmeBlogBundle
```

Your `AppKernel.php` should now contain the line:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new Acme\Bundle\AcmeBlogBundle(),
    );

    // ...

   return $bundles;
```

Afterwards the error message will be gone and you'll be able to generate your Entity with:

```
app/console doctrine:generate:crud --entity=AcmeBlogBundle:Entity
```